# ode systems including linear and nonlinear equations

Tags: ode, nonlinear-functions

I am dealing with ode equations that are both nonlinear and linear and change over time. I have solved them using scipy integrate odint, but with changing t_span the result will change unexpectedly e.g. results at time span of between zero to one will not correspond to time span zero to 0.

```py
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

# Define parameters and functions
t0 = 0.0
T = 1
N = 10 # Number of time steps
A = np.array([10**14, 4 * 10**13, 10**15, 10**12])
E = np.array([2.24e-19, 2.03e-19, 2.24e-19, 1.4e-19])
h = np.array([1.714e6, 257e5, 3.14e5, 3.78e4])
kb = 1.38 * (10**(-23))
z_t0 = 0.33
C = 1.1  # Battery heat capacity (J/K)
R_conv = 10  # Convective heat transfer coefficient (W/K)
R_rad = 0.8  # Radiative heat transfer coefficient (W/K)
M = 0.72

def ode_system(y, t):
    x_a, x_c, x_s, z, soc, tem = y
    # if x_a <= 0 or x_c <= 0 or x_s <= 0 or soc <= 0:
    #     return [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    dx_adt = -A[0] * x_a * math.exp(-E[0] / (tem * kb))
    dx_cdt = A[1] * x_c * (1 - x_c) * math.exp(-E[1] / (tem * kb))

    try:
        deli1 = math.exp(-E[2] * (-z) / (tem * kb * z_t0))
    except OverflowError:
        deli1 = np.inf

    dx_sdt = -A[2] * x_s * deli1
    deli2 = np.exp(-E[2] * (-z) / (tem * kb * z_t0))
    try:
        deli2 = math.exp(-E[2] * (-z) / (tem * kb * z_t0))
    except OverflowError:
        deli2 = np.inf
    dzdt = A[0] * x_s * deli2
    dsocdt = -A[3] * (1 - x_c) * x_a * math.exp(-E[3] / (tem * kb))

    def total_heat_generation():
        Q_xa = 0.13 * h[0] * dx_adt
        Q_s = -0.13 * h[1] * dx_sdt
        Q_c = 0.29 * h[2] * dx_cdt
        Q_isc = -0.37 * h[3] * dsocdt
        Q_TR = Q_xa + Q_s + Q_c + Q_isc
        return Q_TR

    dTdt = total_heat_generation() / M * C + (R_conv * (tem - 298) - R_rad * (tem ** 4 - 298 ** 4)) / M * C*100/32

    return [dx_adt, dx_cdt, dx_sdt, dzdt, dsocdt, dTdt]

# Set the time span, initial conditions
t_span = np.linspace(t0, T, N+1)
initial_conditions = [0.75, 0.04, 0.015, 0.033, 1, 298]

# Solve the ODEs using odeint
y_values = odeint(ode_system, initial_conditions, t_span)

# Extract individual solutions
x_av, x_cv, x_sv, z_v, socv, temv = y_values.T

# Example: Plotting the results
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(t_span, x_av, label='x_a')
plt.plot(t_span, x_cv, label='x_c')
plt.plot(t_span, x_sv, label='x_s')
plt.plot(t_span, socv, label='SOC')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Concentration Profiles')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Concentration')
plt.show()
print("x_av[1]:", x_av[1])
print("socv[1]:", socv[1])
x_av
```